# Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:

Tags: php, angularjs, slim

Broken interceptor detected: Config object not supplied in rejection:
I'm getting this error when I call the post method.

I have given Services, Controller, and PHP Code

Services

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
.factory('Branch', function($resource){
    return $resource('api/branchdetails/:branch_id',{branch_id:'@_branch_id'},{
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
     });
 })
.service('popupService',function($window){
    this.showPopup=function(message){
        return $window.confirm(message);
    }
});
```

Controller

```
angular.module('sbAdminApp')
.controller('BranchDetailsController', function($scope,$state,$stateParams,$window,Branch){

        $scope.branch = new Branch();

        $scope.addBranch=function(){                 
          $scope.branch.$save(function(){
              $state.go('branchdetails');
         });
    }
});
```

PHP Code

```
<?php

require_once('Slim/Slim.php');
require_once('dbconnection.php');

$app = new Slim();
$app->post('/branchdetails','addBranch');
$app->run();
function addBranch() {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $branch = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO branch(branch_name, branch_address, branch_phno, branch_mobileno, branch_contactperson, branch_createdate, branch_modifieddate) VALUES (:branch_name,:branch_address, :branch_phno, :branch_mobileno, :branch_contactperson, :branch_createdate, :branch_modifieddate)";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_name", $branch->branch_name);
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_address", $branch->branch_address);
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_phno", $branch->branch_phno);
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_mobileno", $branch->branch_mobileno);
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_contactperson", $branch->branch_contactperson);
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_createdate", $branch->branch_createdate);
        $stmt->bindParam("branch_modifieddate", $branch->branch_modifieddate);
        $stmt->execute();
        $branch->branch_id = $db->lastInsertId();
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($branch); 
    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }

}



?>
```

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: it's angular issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you have a `interceptor` for `$httpProvider` which doesn't have a proper response error section, something like this :

```
(function () {
    angular.module('App')               
           .config(['$httpProvider', httpProviderConfig]);

    function httpProviderConfig($httpProvider) {

        var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function ($rootScope, $q) {

            return {

                'responseError': function (rejection) {

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            };
        }];

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
    }
})();
```

Comment: even i'm getting another error like this "SyntaxError: Unexpected token S
    at Object.parse (native)"

Comment: I did not say keep the interceptor, i said find it, search all your angular files for `$httpProvider` and see when i has been used?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error could also occur when the API is not returning a valid JSON.

AngularJS transform Response will try to parse the response as JSON if the Content-Type header is `application/json`, or the response looks like a valid JSON-stringified object or array.

First, always try to receive a valid JSON object from the backend. Second, also handle errors in callback functions.

That's good practice. If you are still not receiving a valid JSON, then handling it in an error callback will also do the trick:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.6/docs/api/ng/service/$http#default-transformations

```
notificationsGET: function () {
    return Restangular.one('getusermenu.php').get({
        menu: 'notification',
        token: sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')
    }).then(function (data) {
        // success callback
        return data;
    }, function (err) {
        // error callback
        console.log('error is ', err);
    }
    );
}
```